# How do I animate along a path

Tags: objective-c

How do I animate UIImageView along a path?

Does anyone know of any tutorials that walk through this?

Comment: Have you tried looking online? Please show some research effort.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  The best questions here are about code, what you have tried and what effort you have made.  Do some research and then ask a specific question.

Comment: I was how you would use key frame animation to do this

Answer (score 0):

CAKayframeAnimation can do so.

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
//your code to configure the path

//configure the animation
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[animation setPath:path];
[animation setDuration:3.0];
CGPathRelease(path);
[self.yourImageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:NULL];
```

Comment: Is there anything needed in the .h file

Comment: nothing about the animation, but you can add your imageView as a property to the viewController

Comment: Would this be a UIView subclass?

Comment: UIImageView, UIKit provides it

Comment: is quartz core animation needed? And just to be sure this does not need to be in a UIView subclass.

Comment: import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>, this code does not need to be in a UIView (actually it's often in a viewController class)

Comment: how would you declare "path" as an identifier?

Comment: what do you mean "identifier"?

Comment: When i used the code it said "self" was an undeclared identifier

Comment: where you put your code in ? you'd better read some introduction of objc and iOS development

Comment: I put the code in where it said to configure your path and once I put that code in is when i got all of the error messages.

Comment: the path in my answer is a local variable. it initializes when the method begins and release before the method ends. So it does not need a self before the path. (when we use self.xxx, the xxx is the instance variable, so use self.xxx to refer to it)